# How do I code a discord bot to extract text from a website?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

My bot is written in javascript but I can use other code languages, I want it to upon the name of a wikipedia article being written after the prefix it to post the first paragraph of that article. I've seen it happen before and can't find any info on it.

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a *"how to"* tutorial service. Read more about how the site works in the [help]

Comment: @charlietfl is correct but here is a tip: try to find an API or parse the DOM using cheerio or something.

Comment: You have to parse it or scrape it. see https://discord.gg/vz7PeKk For wikipedia, however there are wikidata APIs